# javascript regex for american phone number

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex expression `var re = /(?:\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))([\w-\/\.]?)\d{3}\1\d{4}/;`, however, the `\w` whitespace doesn't work on this test `console.log(re.test('123 456 7890'));`

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bqb22/

Comment: @M42 Does this regex look comprehensive? I wouldn't call this a duplicate. It's true that the OP might benefit from looking at a more comprehensive solution, but that doesn't make this a duplicate.

Comment: Psst, "American" phone numbers are continent-wide, including most of the Caribbean.

Comment: Not exactly connected with your question, but I recommend http://refiddle.com/ for testing regex. For me testing regex there is easier and faster than in the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't use `\w` for whitespace. Use `\s` instead. (`\w` is word character, the same as `[0-9A-Za-z_]`, and should not be used to indicate whitespace).

Comment: Haha.  Nice quick edit.  I was testing your previous answer and it was not working.  Now it does.  Proof is in the pudding: `var a = "123 456 7890"; a.match(/(?:\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))([\s-\/\.]?)\d{3}\1\d{4}/); // returns ["123 456 7890", " "]`.  +1 BTW

Comment: **\s = space** and **\w = word**.  But sometimes you think \w is whitespace! ;)

Comment: So I was looking at a table and reading the description for \s but kept typing \w for some reason...